# Angular to display last 12 months dates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I am trying to write  simple ng-repeat that displays a list of the last 12 months, from today.

So for example, if i load my application today (May 2014), i will have a list of:

```
May 2014
Apr 2014
Mar 2014
Feb 2014
Jan 2014
Dec 2013
Nov 2013
Oct 2013
Sep 2013
Aug 2013
Jul 2013
Jun 2013
```

If i was to view on say, September 2014, then the list would display as:

```
Sep 2014
Aug 2014
Jul 2014
Jun 2014
May 2014
Apr 2014
Mar 2014
Feb 2014
Jan 2014
Dec 2013
Nov 2013
Oct 2013
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="currMonth in months">{{currMonth}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.months = [
      "01 - Jan",
      "02 - Feb",
      "03 - Mar",
      "04 - Apr",
      "05 - May",
      "06 - Jun",
      "07 - Jul",
      "08 - Aug",
      "09 - Sep",
      "10 - Oct",
      "11 - Nov",
      "12 - Dec"
    ];
    $scope.month = 'null';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the logic yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is fairly simple and really not anything angularjs related. That being said, I wanted to try it out for myself and this is what I came up with.

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    var date = new Date();
    var months = [],
        monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                       "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        months.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());

        // Subtract a month each time
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
    }
    $scope.months = months;
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6MLQ/) I used to create it.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was after. I prefer to keep my controllers quite simple, can this be put into a function as per: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/Z6MLQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since we are using angular, take advantage on $filter directives

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
   
   $scope.premonths = 12;
  
   $scope.getMonths = function(){
        $scope.months = [];
        var today = new Date();
        var endDate = new Date()
       endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() - $scope.premonths)

      for(var d=today;d > endDate;d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1)) {  
     $scope.months.push({month:($filter('date')(d, 'MMMM')),year:$filter('date')(d,     'yyyy')}) 
   }
  
    }

  $scope.getMonths();
});
```

```css
input {
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app='test'>
<body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  Get last <input ng-model='premonths' ng-change='getMonths()'> months 
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='month in months'>
    {{month.month}} - {{ month.year}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```